# Write Avro in ruby and read in Python

Tags: python, ruby, avro

I'm facing issues trying to decode Avro bytes written in Ruby to a Kafka topic. On eyeballing the avro byte string I can see that it looks fine. But when I try to decode, I get a 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 32: invalid start byte'.

```
import avro.schema
import avro.io
import io

bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(m.value)
decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
print reader.read(decoder)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the code this way solved the problem

```
bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(msg.value)
reader = DataFileReader(bytes_reader, DatumReader())
for r in reader:
    print r
```